# How to configure for Istio Multi-Primary on different networks

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I tried to configure istio multicluster in different networkg using https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/ in AWS EC2 instances.

Tried creating 2 clusters and tried to verify the communication between cluster, but is failing.

In Istio doc, I found this statement "**The API Server in each cluster must be accessible to the other clusters in the mesh**" under https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/before-you-begin/. How to make API Server accessible to other cluster?

Answer (score 1):

In the same link which you had used https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/multi-primary_multi-network/ the steps are there to provide access to api server.

Install a remote secret in cluster2 that provides access to cluster1’s API server.

```
$ istioctl x create-remote-secret \
  --context="${CTX_CLUSTER1}" \
  --name=cluster1 | \
  kubectl apply -f - --context="${CTX_CLUSTER2}"
```

Install a remote secret in cluster1 that provides access to cluster2’s API server.

```
$ istioctl x create-remote-secret \
  --context="${CTX_CLUSTER2}" \
  --name=cluster2 | \
  kubectl apply -f - --context="${CTX_CLUSTER1}"
```